# jpa stored procedure resultset type mapping

Tags: java

my stored procedure returns a table like below

```
no  |  name
------------
1   |  'tom'
2   |  'clark'
...
more rows....
```

and this colums has type like

```
no = int
name = varchar
```

it always map **no** column into int.
but, I want to get **no** with long not int

```
class Result {
  long no;
  String name;
}
```

like this pojo

how can I do this ?